# Tag wiki suggested edits don't hide edit link in revisions

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, revisions-list

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/333189

1. Tag wiki was edited.
2. Suggested edit was approved by one user.
3. On the tag wiki page https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/astra-linux/info **edit button is disabled**. But you can open history page and press **edit**:

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. Change tag wiki.
5. Original edit suggestion automatically declined with message "This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit".

   > [image]

Why was edit button on the tag wiki page disabled, but the same button was enabled on history page?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: Not a duplicate: Step #3 in this question should not have been possible and is a bug.

Comment: I [just tested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/62678), and it seems the same bug occurs for posts too.